# Swift 2.1 | Swift условия оператора if

Tags: swift

Всем привет!

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему Swift не принимает подобное условия:

```
let x = 1
let y = 2
let z = 3

if x < y < z {
    print("Yes")
} else {
    print("No")
}
```

Как правильно его записать?

Альтернативный вариант записи такой.

```
if (x < y) && (y < z) {
    print("Yes")
} else {
    print("No")
}
```

Но возможно ли записать условие как в первом варианте?

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще 1 вариант, если вы хотите чтобы явно было видно что вы проверяете входит ли число в диапазон:

```
if (x..< z).contains(y) {
    print("Yes")
} else {
    print("No")
}
```

Либо используйте свой альтернативный вариант.

Comment: не будет так работать. если z меньше x то крэшится 'fatal error: Can't form Range with end < start'

Comment: Я знаю, я всего лишь показал альтернативный способ, если он уверен что х всегда будет меньше чем z, то помоему этот способ элегантнее, хотя и работать будет медленее :)

Comment: способ сам по себе интересный - не знал о таком

Answer (score 1):

> Как правильно его записать?

`if (x < y) && (y < z)`

> Но возможно ли записать условие как в первом варианте?

Невозможно по правилам языка.